# Проблема c SASS лоадером из Vue приложения

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass

решил подключить препроцессор SASS к моему приложению, но выдает следующую ошибку():

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| header
|     width: 100%
>     height: 50px
|     background-color: white
|     border-bottom: 1px solid #ACB1B4
```

Подключаю следующим образом:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
        loaders: {
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="scss">
            sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax' // <style lang="sass">
        }
    }
 },
```

Использую:

```
<style scoped lang="sass">

    header
        width: 100%
        height: 50px
        background-color: white
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ACB1B4

</style>
```

Зависимости:

```
"dependencies": {
    "fabric": "^2.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "log4js": "^4.0.2",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
    "vue-loader": "^15.6.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.6",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.0"
```

}

Может подскажите в чем может быть проблема, так как не знаю что уже делать...

Comment: А как приложение создавали? Я через vue create делаю, проблем не испытывал никогда. Или уже в процессе было решено использовать сасс?

Comment: `;` поставьте в конце строк

Comment: В процессе, обычные стили без препроцессинга отлично работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте подключить sass-loader так:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader'
}, {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['vue-style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
}, {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: ['vue-style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader?indentedSyntax']
}
```

vue-loader вызовет нужные лоадеры, основываясь на значении атрибута lang